# How I can set a default value in json-schema if not exists other property?

Tags: php, json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I've two not mandatory properties in a json-schema. If both are missing I need to set a default in one of them

```
{
   "type":"object",
   "required":["foo"]
   "properties": {
      "foo": { "type": "string"},
      "expires_on_date": {
        "type": "string",
        "format": "date-time"
      },
      "expires_on_duration": {
        "type": "string",
        "format": "duration"
      }
   }

}
```

I need the following results:

| input | output |
| --- | --- |
| `{"foo":"baz"}` | `{"foo":"baz", "expires_on_duration": "P2D"}` |
| `{"foo":"baz", "expires_on_duration": "P4D"}` | `{"foo":"baz", "expires_on_duration": "P4D"}` |
| `{"foo":"baz", "expires_on_date": "2023-01-18T01:01:01"}` | `{"foo":"baz", , "expires_on_date": "2023-01-18T01:01:01"}` |
| `{"foo":"baz", "expires_on_date": "2023-01-18T01:01:01", "expires_on_duration": "P4D"}` | `ERROR` |

Is that possible??

Comment: Did you check this solution? -> https://opis.io/json-schema/1.x/default-value.html

Comment: @OleksiiHudzishevskyi this solution does not fit for me because if I pass expire_on_date the json_schema return both expire_on_duration and expire_on_date

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can use a mixture of [`oneOf`](http://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/combining.html#oneof) and [`not`](http://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/combining.html#not) to model the for cases. In the example below, the first case both are missing and a `default` is defined, case 2 and 3 are are one of them is present. Case 4 is not modeled and will be declined by the validation. Check it out here: https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/JylB1slX

```js
{
    "type": "object",
    "required": [
        "foo"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "foo": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "oneOf": [
        {
            "properties": {
                "expires_on_duration": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "format": "duration",
                    "default": "P2D"
                },
                "expires_on_date": { "not": {} }
            },
            "not": {
                "required": ["expires_on_duration"]
            }
        },
        {
            "properties": {
                "expires_on_duration": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "format": "duration"
                },
                "expires_on_date": { "not": {} }
            },
            "required": ["expires_on_duration"]
        },
        {
            "properties": {
                "expires_on_date": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "format": "date-time"
                },
                "expires_on_duration": { "not": {} }
            },
            "required": ["expires_on_date"]
        }
    ]
}
```

However, setting the default is tricky as this depends on the jsonschema library you're using. The [jsonschema docs](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/generic.html#annotations) specifically say that `default` is more of a documentation property.